# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

this is a first time i am doing a simple spring boot crud i ran in to the problem with

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

i don't how to solve the problem I added in drivers correct way but I got the error pls solve this problem

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mlab
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

**porm.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you failed to provide driver-class name.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mlab
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

You can refer to : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source

It should be work after adding the above mentioned properties.

Comment: can you please check if you have added `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>` in pom.xml

Comment: <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> here i addedd

Comment: is it possible for you to share entire code base via github? I can't think of anything else from top of my head. Maybe after looking at entire code base, I might be able to help.

Comment: Before that, can you try renaming the driver-property name as `spring.datasource.driverClassName`

Comment: n: The server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mlab?serverTimezone=UTC`. this should solve the problem. By the way, changing `driverClassName` worked, or was there something else that did the trick?

Comment: try adding `useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC` or `jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding driver class in **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

You can also add the following and modify as per your need

```
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Comment: spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mlab
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=                       i added this sames error